# Not be able to register on spotify tool

Tags: node.js, express, spotify

I'm trying to register on spotify either create an account or facebook login. But not get login.

1. When I try login by facebook then return message

   > You do not have a Spotify account connected to your Facebook account. If you have a Spotify account, please log in with your Spotify credentials. If you do not have a Spotify account, sign up.
2. When I create an account by register

   > It takes more time but returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a region where Spotify is not supported, this often is the case, try using VPN.